# Problems with using variable bounds and objective function in C++ CPLEX

Tags: c++, cplex

I am writing a linear programming model in C++ unsing the concert technology from cplex.

I declare the variables and the objective function of my model like this:

```
IloModel genInst (env);

IloNumVarArray Sizes(env,N,0.25+EPS,1.0-EPS);

IloObjective Weight = IloAdd(genInst, IloMaximize(env,IloSum(Sizes));
```

EPS is a small constant, because I want the variables to be strictly larger than 0.25 and strictly smaller than 1.0.

The objective function should just maximize the sum of all variables, but whenever I try this, the variables in the solution will have values outside my restriction (e.g. smaller than 0.25 or too large) and I don't see any possibilities to keep the variable values in their range.

Can someone please help me? I probably made some mistake because it shouldn't be that complicated. Thanks you!

Comment: A good way to troubleshoot CPLEX is to use exportModel. Check the bounds in your .LP file and see if they match your expectations. Try to solve the problem with a different solver, like Gurobi, and see what values you get.

Also, When you say the values are outside your restriction after you solve, what values do you get? What exactly is the value of EPS?

Comment: Thanks, exportModel helped me to find the reason, my constraints always contained a negative variable, which should have been positive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bounding function:

```
template<class T>
T bound_number(T n, T min, T max) {
    return std::max(std::min(n, max), min);
}
```

Comment: Better yet, use `std::min` and `std::max` and don't clutter the identifier space with single-use macros.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure if this would work because it seems to be a cplex specific problem. The bounds are satisfied but whenever I set the objectiv function, the variable start lying outside the bounds.